# Nested XML to DataTable

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, nested, zendesk

I have the following XML:

```
<tickets>
     <ticket>
          <subject>ABC</subject>
          <entries-field>
               <entry-field>
                    <field-id>12345</field-id>
                    <value>New</value>
               </entry-field>
          <entries-field>
     <ticket>
     <ticket>
          <subject>DEF</subject>
          <entries-field>
               <entry-field>
                    <field-id>67890</field-id>
                    <value>category_cc</value>
               </entry-field>
               <entry-field>
                    <field-id>12345</field-id>
                    <value>Pending</value>
               </entry-field>
          <entries-field>
     <ticket>
     <ticket>
          <subject>GHI</subject>
     <ticket>
</tickets>
```

I need to convert it into C# data table as following:

```
Subject          Status
------------------------
ABC              New
DEF              Pending
GHI
```

I try many methods but no luck.
Kindly appreciate if anyone can give a good idea.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an Idea:

1. Parse the XML File and iterate for each `ticket` the `subject` and get the `value` for each `<field-id>12345</field-id>`
2. fill all data in a Dictionary with `subject` as Key and the `value` as a Value, if not found leave it empty

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the real xml you work with is not corrupt as above

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var result = xDoc.Descendants("ticket")
                 .Select(n => new
                    {
                        Subject = n.Element("subject").Value,
                        Status = (string)n.Descendants("value").LastOrDefault()
                    })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: the Status seems allways to be the Value of field 12345